# Are questions about the knowledge to know what type of music to use/listen to on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it's clear that "recommendations of pieces to listen to, study, or play, or that meet particular criteria" are off-topic. However, would asking what knowledge one need to know to search for such pieces on-topic?

Below is my draft.

---

> I am making a video for a friend to ask for their help, because my problem is complicate and they don't have time to fully investigate it. Each sentence I say will uncover some thing they do not know, and they may need to digest it/verify it before accepting my words. Only after seeing that my rational is reasonable that they can have the reason to help me. In other words, it's not about uplifting them, but about encouraging them to investigate the problem with me. The video is basically a long elevator pitch.
>
> What knowledge I need to find the suitable background music? In what way a piece of music can be composed to reflect the mood of curiosity and skeptical?

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no single answer (any choice of music may suit some people but not others) it would be off topic here as too broad.

Why not choose music that means something to you or to your friend?

Comment: But the knowledge is not a preferable thing. Like how to use silence effectively, how do composers make music that suits a scene, etc. Why are those questions broad?

Comment: There are courses that are multiple years long on composing and score arrangement. This site is not set up for that sort of thing.

Comment: @Ooker both of those question are not something that an SE post alone can teach you. They require a lot of time and study to grasp while examining other's work and getting your own critiqued.  Both answers also vary greatly based on the exactly what you are personally going for.  I'd love to have more composition based questions on this SE, but there should be a goal and technique in mind to best break down the subject.